# JQuery Tools Scrollable Steps not working?

Tags: jquery, carousel, jquery-tools, scrollable

I am using JQuery Tools to create a simple slideshow of images/text (5 per row), is works fine but it moves at 1 step per time and I set it to 5, but it just doesn't work. Any clues?

http://jsfiddle.net/L79La/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the scrollable plugin from jquery tools, but you could try playing with the size value to see if it gives you the functionality you desire:

```
jQuery(".scrollable").scrollable({circular: true, size:5}).autoscroll({ 
        autoplay: false,
        interval: 3000,
        autopause: true,
        steps: 1
      });​
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/L79La/27/

Comment: Thank you sir, never even thought about using size!!